# NSUrlSession background mode when getting json

Tags: ios, json

I am getting json from my server with `nsurlsession` but my code is not working in background. How can I run this code in background? I couldn't find background configuration for `dataTaskWithRequest` it looks only for downloading operation but i am not downloading any file.

My code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "url")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "search=\(username)&me=\(anonId)"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            print("step 2")
            if error == nil {
                let jsonResult: Dictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                let results = jsonResult["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                print(results)
                for item in results {

                }
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Where and how is `completionHandler` defined? And how did you check that it did not run in background?

Comment: I am calling this in didreceivenotification method. I am using silent notifications.